# How do I entirely remove the label from a CheckBox?

Tags: javafx, checkbox, javafx-8

I want my JavaFX CheckBox to have *no label*.

Context: it's in the header of a TableColumn and it's (empahsis:) *off-center*.

I tried removing the *label's text*, but there's still some space on the right:

[image: CheckBox with space]

Next I tried changing the *[Content Display](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ContentDisplay.html)*, but that didn't work either.

How do I get a CheckBox without a label or an extra space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out!

[SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/)'s CSS Analyzer <sub>(Ctrl + 6)</sub>, shows me that CheckBoxes have some [label padding](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled) there on the right side:

[image: label padding amounts]

To fix it,

1. remove the checkbox's text
2. add the following CSS to your stylesheet or directly to the CheckBox

Stylesheet:

```
.no-label-checkbox {
    -fx-label-padding: 0;
}
```

SceneBuilder:

[image: setting the style class]

Comment: Though it's impressive that you answered your answer, I'm more impressed that your answer came almost the same second as your question.

Comment: Thanks, @Jai. As our friend Jeff says, ["To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).